# Probability of sum of two discrete uniform random variables modulo k

Tags: probability-theory

Let U and V be two dependent discrete random variables, each
being uniformly distributed on {1, 2, . . . , k}. Let W be another
random variable having the same uniform distribution but independent of U and V . Define a random variable X = (V + W)
mod k. Show that
(a) X is uniformly distributed on {0, 1, 2, . . . , k − 1},
(b) U and X are independent.

P(X=0)=P(V+W=k)+P(V+W=2k)
P(X=i)=P(V+W=i)+P(V+W=k+i)
Nit being able to bring it in the form of discrete uniform (0,1,2,..,k-1)
Please help

And also how to approach the second part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**(a)** Fix any $0\leq \ell\leq k-1$.
$$\begin{align}
\Pr[X=\ell] &= \Pr[V+W=\ell \bmod k] \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^k \Pr[V=i, (W+i=\ell\bmod k)] \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^k \Pr[V=i]\Pr[W+i=\ell\bmod k] \tag{$V,W$ independent}\\
&= \sum_{i=1}^k \frac{1}{k}\cdot\frac{1}{k} \tag{$V,W$ uniform}\\&=\frac{1}{k}
\end{align}$$
where we used the fact that, for any $a\in \mathbb{Z}$, there exists a unique $1\leq b\leq k$ such that $a = b \bmod k$.

This shows that $X$ is indeed uniform on $\{0,1,2,\dots, k-1\}$.

**(b)** To prove that $U$ and $X$ are independent, let us compute, for $0\leq i \leq k-1$, $1\leq j\leq k$,
\begin{align*}
\Pr[X=i, U=j]
&= \sum_{\ell=1}^k \Pr[X=i, U=j, V=\ell]\\
&= \sum_{\ell=1}^k \Pr[V+W=i \bmod k, U=j, V=\ell] \\
&= \sum_{\ell=1}^k \Pr[W=i-\ell \bmod k, U=j, V=\ell] \\
&= \sum_{\ell=1}^k \Pr[W=i-\ell \bmod k]\Pr[U=j, V=\ell]  \tag{$W\perp \!\!\! \perp (U,V)$}\\
&= \frac{1}{k}\sum_{\ell=1}^k \Pr[U=j, V=\ell]  \tag{$W$ uniform}\\
&= \frac{1}{k}\Pr[U=j] \\
&= \Pr[X=i]\Pr[U=j]  \tag{$X$ uniform}
\end{align*}
showing the independence.

Answer (score 0):

a) For $x\in \{0,1,\ldots, k-1\}$,
$$
\mathsf{P}(X=x)=\sum_{\substack{1\le, v,w\le k \\ (v+w \mod k)=x}}\mathsf{P}(V=v)\mathsf{P}(W=w)=\sum_{\substack{1\le, v,w\le k \\ (v+w \mod k)=x}}\frac{1}{k^2}.
$$
Since there are $k$ combinations of $v$ and $w$ s.t. $(v + w \mod k) = x$,
$$
\mathsf{P}(X=x)=\frac{1}{k}.
$$

b) Since $W$ is independent of $U$ and $V$,
\begin{align}
\mathsf{P}(X=x\mid U=u)&=\sum_{\substack{1\le, v,w\le k \\ (v+w \mod k)=x}}\mathsf{P}(V=v\mid U=u)\mathsf{P}(W=w) \\
&=\sum_{\substack{1\le, v,w\le k \\ (v+w \mod k)=x}}\mathsf{P}(V=v\mid U=u) \times \frac{1}{k} \\
&=\sum_{1\le v\le k}\mathsf{P}(V=v\mid U=u)\times \frac{1}{k} \\
&= 1\times \frac{1}{k}=\mathsf{P}(X=x)
\end{align}
because $\sum_{1\le v\le k}\mathsf{P}(V=v\mid U=u)=1$.